# blackberry device not detected when debugging on Mac

Tags: java, macos, debugging, blackberry

I have a problem when I want to debug my application from eclipse using device (I use 9700 for debugging). It's used to be like this: the device is connected to Mac using usb cable, and automatically desktop manager pops up, gives sign that my device is successfully connected, thus I can debug my project from eclipse.

Now I can't do it like that anymore. when I connect the device to Mac, desktop manager (or Mac) doesn't detect my device. I use:

- Desktop Manager 2.3.1 build 5
- BlackBerry Java Plug-in Version: 1.5.2.201204302029

Does anybody know how I can make my device be detected again by the system?

Answer (score 1):

You might compare the results from either of these two USB utilities:

- `/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app`
- `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/USB Prober.app`